# Android 7.1.2 implicit intent 'No apps can perform this action'

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-support-library, android-7.1-nougat

Only on android 7.1.2, I am unable to launch implicit intents within my app if I have more than one variant of my app installed on the same device.

I have multiple application variants of the same app, each with different applicationId, but same java package.

In build.gradle:

```
android {
defaultConfig.applicationId 'com.myapp.appid'
buildTypes {
    debug.applicationIdSuffix 'foo'
    beta.applicationIdSuffix 'bar'
}}
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml, I have defined an activity which I will launch implicitly within my app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
        package="com.myapp.mypackage">
    <application
            android:name="com.myapp.mypackage.MyApplication">
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.mypackage.MyActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.myapp.mypackage.MyActivity" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I start this activity in java like so:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.myapp.mypackage.MyActivity");
ActivityCompat.startActivity( activity, intent, bundle );
```

With both the 'debug' and 'beta' buildTypes installed on the same device, before 7.1.2 startActivity would just work without the user even having to choose the app to handle the intent in ResolveActivity. Now in 7.1.2, the ResolveActivity app chooser opens up empty and says 'No apps can perform this action.'

When I observe the results of

```
getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY );
```

I do see both of the installed versions as results

```
com.myapp.appid.foo/com.myapp.mypackage.MyActivity
com.myapp.appid.bar/com.myapp.mypackage.MyActivity
```

[But the user cannot proceed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSkpJ.png)

Comment: try to give your application a name tag

Comment: Thanks Arash. My application does have a name tag. I just left that out of here for brevity. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It's a bug in Android. It's been reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37576886

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar situation with multiple app variants using the same Java package and launching activities by implicit intent.

In the end, the easiest solution was to limit the implicit intent search to just the current app:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.myapp.mypackage.MyActivity");
i.setPackage(context.getPackageName());
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same issue.  I was able to fix it by switching to explicit intents.